# How can I optimize loops through a multidimensional array?

Tags: python

After gathering some 3D netCDF data on Python 3, I am in the process of looping through each x,y data point to calculate another variable. The calculation of this variable is dependent upon the z for a given x,y point. The code seems to be running correctly but is awfully slow; I am wondering if anyone has suggestions on how to optimize the code to have it run more quickly.

I've gone from a lengthier code that defined many intermediate variables to something rather bare bones, which is shown here. Even after trimming the code, it runs slowly (i.e., a few minutes for each i in the outer for loop).

```
for i in range(0,217):
    print(i)
    for j in range(0,301):
        for k in range(10,30):
            if (data.variables[longvars[v][2]][0][k][i][j]-data.variables[longvars[v][3]][0][i][j]) <= 3000.0:
                break

        if (abs(data.variables[longvars[v][2]][0][k][i][j]-data.variables[longvars[v][3]][0][i][j])-3000.) \
         < (abs(data.variables[longvars[v][2]][0][k-1][i][j]-data.variables[longvars[v][3]][0][i][j])-3000.):
            lev = k
        else:
            lev = k-1

        newd[i][j] = np.sqrt(((data.variables[longvars[v][0]][0][lev][i][j]-data.variables[longvars[v][4]][0][0][i][j])**2)+((data.variables[longvars[v][1]][0][lev][i][j]-data.variables[longvars[v][5]][0][0][i][j])**2))
```

I imagine there may be a way to do this with another array that stores the correct z (k) level for each x,y (i,j) point, then runs the calculation over the entire array of data. However, I don't know that it would be any faster. I appreciate any help that folks can provide!

Answer (score 0):

The logic looks sound, but we can optimize it a bit further using generators and comprehensions.

Let's isolate the inner logic into a function called `findZValue`.

```
def findZValue(v, i, j, variables, longvars, np):
```

Forgive me if I am reading this wrong, but it looks like you are trying to find the index of the value closest to 3000? If so first we will make a generator that returns a tuple containing the index and the absolute value of "variable - variable - 3000":

```
def findZValue(v, i, j, variables, longvars, np):
    lev = ((k, abs(variables[longvars[v][2]][0][k][i][j] - variables[longvars[v][3]][0][i][j] - 3000)) for k in range(10, 30))
```

In order to get the value we want, we wrap the whole thing in a `min` function (with the key saying we want it sorted by the second value) and specify we want to get the index (i.e. the first value in the tuple returned by `min`):

```
def findZValue(v, i, j, variables, longvars, np):
    lev = min(((k, abs(variables[longvars[v][2]][0][k][i][j] - variables[longvars[v][3]][0][i][j] - 3000)) for k in range(10, 30)), key = lambda t: t[1])[0]
```

For the value put into "newd" it looks like you are taking the root of the sum of the squares (i.e. its normalization or magnitude). Luckily numpy (which is what I assume "np" is) has a built-in-method for finding the magnitude/normalization of an array: np.linalg.norm. All we have to do is put the other values into an np.array and then call it on them:

```
def findZValue(v, i, j, variables, longvars, np):
    lev = min(((k, abs(variables[longvars[v][2]][0][k][i][j] - variables[longvars[v][3]][0][i][j] - 3000)) for k in range(10, 30)), key = lambda t: t[1])[0]
    return np.linalg.norm(np.array(variables[longvars[v][0]][0][lev][i][j]-variables[longvars[v][4]][0][0][i][j], variables[longvars[v][1]][0][lev][i][j]-variables[longvars[v][5]][0][0][i][j]))
```

Now we can put the entire loop into a nested comprehension:

```
newd = [[findZValue(v, i, j, data.variables, longvars, np) for j in range(301)] for i in range(217)]

def findZValue(v, i, j, variables, longvars, np):
    lev = min(((k, abs(variables[longvars[v][2]][0][k][i][j] - variables[longvars[v][3]][0][i][j] - 3000)) for k in range(10, 30)), key = lambda t: t[1])[0]

    return np.linalg.norm(np.array(variables[longvars[v][0]][0][lev][i][j]-variables[longvars[v][4]][0][0][i][j], variables[longvars[v][1]][0][lev][i][j]-variables[longvars[v][5]][0][0][i][j]))
```

Using generators and comprehensions should speed things up over using for loops. But if you really want to crank things up we can use "multiprocessing". Specifically, a multiprocessing pool. In order to do so we will need to create a second function to handle each vector (this is due to restrictions on how multiprocessing pools work):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def findZValue(v, i, j, variables, longvars, np):
    lev = min(((k, abs(variables[longvars[v][2]][0][k][i][j] - variables[longvars[v][3]][0][i][j] - 3000)) for k in range(10, 30)), key = lambda t: t[1])[0]

    return np.linalg.norm(np.array(variables[longvars[v][0]][0][lev][i][j]-variables[longvars[v][4]][0][0][i][j], variables[longvars[v][1]][0][lev][i][j]-variables[longvars[v][5]][0][0][i][j]))

def findZValuesForVector(vector):
    return [findZValue(*values) for values in vector]

with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
    newd = pool.map(findZValuesForVector, [[[v, i, j, data.variables, longvars, np] for j in range(301)] for i in range(217)])
```

You can alter the number of "processes" created for the pool to see what gives you the best results.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! When including the multiprocessing function, I am receiving an error: "Variable [referring to the netCDF4 variable, data.variables] is not picklable". Should this first be converted to an array?

Comment: @donutwx Apologies for the late reply. As long as the relevant data remains the same, I would say yes. "Not picklable" just means that the object is complicated (likely has references to other objects) and thus can't be converted to a simple serial object for `map` to work on. Since all we care about are the values in data.variables, converting it to an array and then passing said values should still give you the results you want.